# Counting the Frequency of Letters in a string (Python)

Tags: python, frequency-analysis

So I'm trying to count the frequency of letters in a user inputted string without using python dictionaries...
I want the output to be as follows (using letter H as an example)

```
"The letter H occurred 1 time(s)."
```

The problem I have is that the program prints the letters in alphabetical order
but I want the program to print the frequency of the letters in the order that they were given in the input...

an example of this would be if I entered "Hello"
the program would print

```
"The letter e occurred 1 time(s)"
"The letter h occurred 1 time(s)"
"The letter l occurred 2 time(s)"
"The letter o occurred 1 time(s)"
```

but I want the output to be as follows

```
"The letter h occurred 1 time(s)"
"The letter e occurred 1 time(s)"
"The letter l occurred 2 time(s)"
"The letter o occurred 1 time(s)"
```

This is the code that I have so far:

```
originalinput = input("")
if originalinput == "":
    print("There are no letters.")
else:
  word = str.lower(originalinput)

  Alphabet= ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

  for i in range(0,26): 
    if word.count(Alphabet[i]) > 0:
      print("The letter", Alphabet[i] ,"occured", word.count(Alphabet[i]), "times")
```

Comment: As explained in the introductory tour, this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers, *not a help forum*. We are not going to do the detailed formatting work, or look up input validation for you: that's *your* job. Please take the tour, visit the help center and especially read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: if `len(originalinput)==0:` throw error? What exactly you are counting is not clear though. Why word-frequency is tagged when you are actually counting letter frequency

Comment: Please explain why no dictionaries.

Comment: -1 and voting to delete because the edit here has invalidated existing answers, I'm not sure if it's appropriate for me to rollback such an edit if it happened post-closure, and I can't see this Q having lasting value anyway.

Comment: I agree I wasnt rlly thinking when I posted this

Comment: feel free to delete whoever has the power to do that as I for some reason cant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just check the input with `if else` and `raise` an Error if needed with a custom message

```
if original_input == "":
    raise RuntimeError("Empty input")
else:
    # Your code goes there
```

As a side not, `input()` is enough, no need to add quotes `""`

Edit: This question was edited, the original question was to check if an input is empty.

Second edit:

If you want your code to print letters as in your output, you should iterate over your word instead over your alphabet:

```
for c in word:
     print("The letter", c ,"occured", word.count(c), "times")
```

Comment: Thanks this was really useful!

Answer (score -1):

As @BlueSheepToken mentioned you can use simple `if` `else` statement. Here is your code below incorporating things that are mentioned.

```
from collections import defaultdict

originalinput = input()

if originalinput == "":
    raise RuntimeError("Empty input")
else:

    result = defaultdict(int)

    for char in list(originalinput.lower()):
        result[char] += 1

    for letter, num in result.items():
        print(f'The letter {letter} occurred {num} time(s)')  

    #Hello
    #The letter h occurred 1 time(s)
    #The letter e occurred 1 time(s)
    #The letter l occurred 2 time(s)
    #The letter o occurred 1 time(s)
```

Using `defaultdict` will help you in this case as all the unused `key`s will be `0`.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using Counter from the collections library.

```
    from collections import Counter

    print(Counter('sample text'))

    #Output: Counter({'t': 2, 'e': 2, 'l': 1, 's': 1, 'a': 1, ' ': 1, 'p': 1, 'm': 1, 'x': 1})
```